# Create List of Strings from Another List of Object Records

Tags: apex, list, developer-console, developer

I am new to Salesforce development and I am trying to practice by creating a list of strings deriving from another list of object records created from a query. My code is the following....

```
public class ProjectStatus{
    public static void Test(List<String> myArray) {
        for (List<pse__Proj__c> projects : [SELECT Id FROM pse__Proj__c WHERE Project_Status_Requirement__c = True LIMIT 1000]) {    
            myArray.add(String.valueOf(projects)); 
        }
    System.debug(myArray);
    }
}
```

After attempting to run in the Anon window, I receive the following error...

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Test() from the type ProjectStatus
```

I ran the following code in the Anon Exec window...

```
ProjectStatus.Test();
```

Could anyone help me identify why this error is being thrown? This is probably a simple beginner's mistake but after spending a lot of time researching and editing my code I am still unsuccessful so I am hoping someone here may be able to add some input, thanks in advance!

Comment: What was your exec anon code? Could you [edit] the code in to your question?

Comment: @sfdcfox updated the post, but here is the code I ran...

ProjectStatus.Test();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the parameter. Try :

```
public class ProjectStatus{
    public static void Test() { // Notice I took out the bit between the ()
        List<String> myArray = new List<String>(); // and added the variable as a local variable

        // Removed the "list<>" from below code
        for (pse__Proj__c p : [SELECT Id FROM pse__Proj__c WHERE Project_Status_Requirement__c = True LIMIT 1000]) {    
            myArray.add(String.valueOf(p)); 
        }

        System.debug(myArray);
    }
}
```

If you wanted to try to use your method as is you would need to call it like so:

```
 List<String> results = new List<String>();
 ProjectStatus.Test(results);
```

Here's some documentation about [method prototypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) that might help you understand. Note, this is not a Salesforce specific issue, it can happen in all programming languages.

[This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) goes over scope to help understand what I mean by a local variable.

### Copy-Pasta

```
public class ProjectStatus{
    public static void Test() { // Notice I took out the bit between the ()
        List<String> myArray = new List<String>(); // and added the variable as a local variable

        for (Account a : [
            SELECT Id 
            FROM Account
            LIMIT 1000
        ]) {    
            myArray.add(String.valueOf(a)); 
        }

        System.debug(myArray);
    }
}
```

Anon:

```
ProjectStatus.Test();
```

Comment: Your modification wouldn't work as is, missing variable definition.

Comment: @gNerb Sorry to bother you, I plan on thoroughly reading through the documentation you have sent, but I also tried changing my code as well as running it as it was with a parameter like you had commented but I am still receiving the following error...

"Method does not exist or incorrect signature"

Comment: I updated my code with copy pasta, please give that a try.

Comment: Hmmm seeing this error now, "duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>"

I wonder if this underlying issue is also preventing me from running successfully? Also wondering if this is related to the metadata I am trying to pull because I am not really doing any data manipulation with this code.

Comment: Shy of a screen sharing session I don't know that I can help you with issues like that.

Comment: @gNerb sounds good, i will keep digging into this issue and try to identify the root cause. I greatly appreciate the help and hope one day I am able to repay the favor! Glad I was able to resolve the original question and your insight added a ton of clarification into that issue, I should really spend more time reading documentation before jumping right into programming with a new language

Comment: @gNerb Working as expected now! I ended up getting frustrated, closed the dev console, reopened it, and attempted to run your copy-pasta after changing the Account object to my project object. 

Why could this have happened? I know for a fact that I attempted to execute the same code in the same manner when you initially added it as a comment and it was throwing errors before, but not after I closed and reopened the dev console. Could not be a cache issue, right?

Answer (score 1):

This error is telling you that you forgot some parameters (in this case, a string list object). You'd call your code like this:

```
String[] values = new String[0];
ProjectStatus.Test(values);
```

Note that your code is directly modifying the values in the parameter, which you can see by using debug:

```
String[] values = new String[0];
ProjectStatus.Test(values);
System.debug(values);
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I tried running with the parameter like you had commented but I am still receiving the following error... 

"Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void Test() from the type ProjectStatus"

Comment: @MaxGoldfarb You still apparently missed the parameter; if you had provided a parameter, the error would have looked different.